# trigger.io narrow chrome preview

Tags: trigger.io

Create new blank trigger.io project. when preview it by "mobile" (in iphone emlulator) its fine. then add preview button in chrome. when click that button preview window show 
http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=screengeg.png but too narrow.

running on macos, triggertoolkit and chrome both in actual stable version.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a "width" attribute in your popup markup:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html {
        width: 500px;
    }
</style>
```